# Asp OpenDB server not found

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

Get 505 error on this command on my asp file due to this code can you tell me fix of this please i will be thankful to you.

```
<%
    OpenDB()
    'Stmt = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE status=1 "
    Stmt = "SELECT * FROM articles, articleCategories WHERE articles.articleID=articleCategories.articleID AND categoryID=1 AND status=1"
    set rsQuery=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsQuery.Open Stmt, OpenDB, 1, 1
    DO WHILE NOT rsQuery.EOF
        wl "<div class=""listSub""><a href=""articles.asp?article=" & rsQuery("articles.articleID") & """>" & rsQuery("title") & "</a></div>"
        rsQuery.MOVENEXT
    LOOP 
    %>
```

Comment: You need to show us your code behind OpenDB.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it i don't about it.

Comment: Thanks i got a fix myself now

Answer (score 0):

First of all do a proper join:

```
 SELECT * FROM articles join articleCategories 
 on articles.articleID=articleCategories.articleID 
 where TableName1.categoryID=1 AND TableName2.status=1
```

Because I do not know if both of your tables have any of those columns(categoryID,status) or just one but sure way to get an error is what you did.
Secon issue is how do you wrote your  OpenDB sub. Need to see to tell you if issue is there or not.
And last but not least, do not do any fancy staff if you do not know how:

```
DO WHILE NOT rsQuery.EOF
   response.write "<div class='"listSub"'><a href='articles.asp?article=" & rsQuery("articles.articleID") & "'>" & rsQuery("title") & "</a></div>"
   rsQuery.MOVENEXT
LOOP
```